# Why isn't TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes returning all attributes?

Tags: c#, attributes, typedescriptor

Code will show it all.  You can drop this in RoslynPad or VS.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple=true, Inherited=true)]
class CategoryOrderAttribute : Attribute{

    public CategoryOrderAttribute(string category, int order){
        Category = category;
        Order    = order;
    }

    public string Category { get; }
    public int    Order    { get; }

    public override string ToString()
        => $"  Category:{Category}, Order:{Order}";
}

[CategoryOrder("Test", 1)]
[CategoryOrder("OtherTest", 2)]
public class TestClass{

    static TestClass(){

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var foundAttributesA = typeof(TestClass)
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CategoryOrderAttribute), true)
            .OfType<CategoryOrderAttribute>();

        sb.AppendLine("Test A");
        foreach(var foundAttribute in foundAttributesA)
            sb.AppendLine(foundAttribute.ToString());

        var foundAttributesB = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(typeof(TestClass))
            .OfType<CategoryOrderAttribute>();

        sb.AppendLine("Test B");
        foreach(var foundAttribute in foundAttributesB)
            sb.AppendLine(foundAttribute.ToString());

        // Add new attribute programmatically
        TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(TestClass),
            new CategoryOrderAttribute("AddedInCode", 42));

        var foundAttributesC = typeof(TestClass)
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CategoryOrderAttribute), true)
            .OfType<CategoryOrderAttribute>();

        sb.AppendLine("Test C");
        foreach(var foundAttribute in foundAttributesC)
            sb.AppendLine(foundAttribute.ToString());

        var foundAttributesD = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(typeof(TestClass))
            .OfType<CategoryOrderAttribute>();

        sb.AppendLine("Test D");
        foreach(var foundAttribute in foundAttributesD)
            sb.AppendLine(foundAttribute.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}

_ = new TestClass();
Console.WriteLine("Tests Done!");
```

The output is as follows:

```
Test A
  Category:Test, Order:1
  Category:OtherTest, Order:2
Test B
  Category:Test, Order:1
Test C
  Category:Test, Order:1
  Category:OtherTest, Order:2
Test D
  Category:AddedInCode, Order:42
```

So my questions are:

1. Why does it only get the first one in 'Test B'
2. Why does it only get the programmatically added one in 'Test D'
3. Why does 'Test C' not get the programmatically added one?

Comment: About C, I think it can only add attributes to the type descriptor, not to the type itself.  I assume this is why you're not asking about D, since D I presume contains the added attribute.

Comment: Also, about B, did you [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.getattributes?view=netframework-4.8)? "When you define a custom attribute with AttributeUsageAttribute.AllowMultiple set to true, you must override the Attribute.TypeId property to make it unique". Adding a `public override object TypeId => this;` makes it return both. Incidentally, this is the problem for D as well.

Comment: Woot!  That last part actually fixed all of them!  Please put that in an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: It doesn't fix C, does it?

Comment: No, but that shows the code in Xceed toolkit shouldn't be using that and should instead be using the `TypeDescriptor`, which is what my question was about, hence you should add that as an answer so I can accept it.  The other questions were just more informative.

Comment: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/issues/1522